# Eerror message in function 'main'

Tags: c

Program to take the input and output the reverse of it:

```
#define MAX 1000 

int readtext(char[],int); /*used to store text in array and 
returns the size of the line*/
void reverse(char[]); /*used to reverse the text in the line and
returns 0*/

int main(void)
{
    char text[MAX];
    printf("Enter text, press Ctrl+d when done \n"); /*prompt user input*/

    while((redtext(text, sizeof text)>0)) /*loop repeats until text size is >0*/
    {
        reverse(text);
        printf("%s\n\n",text);
    }
    return 0;
}

int readtext(char a[],int len)
{
    int letchar,i;

    for(i=0;i<len-1 && (letchar=getchar())!=EOF && letchar!='\n';i++) /*for loop repeats until end of line*/
        a[i]=letchar;
    if(letchar=='\n') /*checks if letchar is \n.  if true, changes it to null and returns i value*/
        a[i++]=letchar;
    a[i]='\0';
    return i;   
}

void reverse(char a[])
{
    char t;
    int x,y;
    for(y=0;a[y]!='\0';y++) /*loop used to get the last element of the array*/
        --y;
    for(x=0;x<y;x++) /*loop used to reverse the array 'a'*/ 
    {
        t=a[x];
        a[x]=a[y];
        a[y]=t;
        --y;
    }
}
```

expected input/output:

```
happy birthday
yadhtrib yppah
```

I am getting this error message, but do not know what it means:

```
/tmp/ccA71SDX.o: In function `main':
1-19.c:(.text+0x63): undefined reference to `redtext'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You have a typo, trying to call function `redtext()` and the actual function name is `readtext()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made a mistake in function call (`redtext` instead of `readtext`). However you can use my solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>

#define MAXSTRLEN 256

void Reverse(char* str);

int main()
{
    printf("Enter string below:\n");
    char str[MAXSTRLEN];

    fgets(str, MAXSTRLEN, stdin);

    Reverse(str);
    printf("Result:\n%s\n", str);

    return 0;
}

void Reverse(char* str)
{
    char tmp;
    int length = strlen(str) - 1;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < length / 2; i++)
    {
        tmp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[length - i - 1];
        str[length - i - 1] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution has two buffer overflows just waiting to happen and a memory leak.

Comment: Thank you, I feel really dumb right now

Comment: Can you explain where? It might be useful for me.

Comment: `gets()` will gladly write past the end of the array you pass it, the `Reverse()` function blindly copies `str` into its own fixed-size buffer, and `strdup()` allocates memory that isn't released in `main()`.

Comment: @Seprum Why not `strdup()` at the beginning instead of `char result[MAXSTRLEN];`?

Comment: Edited `Reverse` function. What is the best way to avoid "gladly  writing past the end of the array"?

Comment: @chux you are right. I just modified function to reverse the string but not return its reversed copy.

Comment: @Seprum: I think the usual suggestion is to use `fgets()` instead but it includes the trailing newline in the string that you then have to deal with. Btw: your updated code is better (I'm not the downvoter).

Comment: @Blastfurnace, thank you for information. I am just student so it's as helpful for me as for the person who've given this question. Modified code. Hope that now everything is ok.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, does `fgets()` calculate `\n` and `\0` to the total count of symbols? So have I to write `fgets(str, MAXSTRLEN - 1, stdin);` or I can just write `fgets(str, MAXSTRLEN, stdin);`?

Comment: No need for -1 in `fgets(str, MAXSTRLEN - 1, stdin);`

Comment: @Seprum: chux is right, `fgets()` reads up to `n-1` characters (including the newline) and then null terminates the string. Just tell it the size of your buffer without the fudge factor.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, chux: thank you for information. Already modified solution.